# Change WordPress Profile Gravatar to generated robohash

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, WordPress admin section allows us to choose from the following Gravatar options:

Mystery Person, Blank, Gravatar Logo, Identicon (Generated), Wavatar (Generated), MonsterID (Generated), Retro (Generated)

However, when I visit https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/. I can see an option for generated robohash. All I have to do is replace `wavatar` in all image URLs with `robohash`.

```
https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/b7556ca086c0d99f2000b73e8f4ce4ea?s=96&d=wavatar&r=g
// will become
https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/b7556ca086c0d99f2000b73e8f4ce4ea?s=96&d=robohash&r=g
```

I can do it on my own vanilla PHP website because I have full control over the HTML on a page. However, I don't know how to use `robohash` avatars on a site with WordPress installation.

First, I thought that I can use JavaScript to select all images on a page and then replace `wavatar` with `robohash` but it seems very unWordPress like and error prone.

Is there a clean and efficient way of doing this like using `add_filter()` etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a default to my custom rest of you need to manage.There below code will change default gravatar:

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'set_new_gravatar' );
function set_new_gravatar($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/new-default-gravatar.png'; // response image URL
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

There is plugin for this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/robohash-avatar/